# How to get react grand-child node to render when child is out of my control

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a react component which uses a 3rd party library Component as a Child node.  The Grand children (or the children of the 3rd party libary) are under my control.  When my component receives new props it re-renders, however the 3rd party component seems to stop my components grand-children from re-rendering also, even though the props my component received, are passed to the non-re-rendering components directly

If I remove the 3rd party component then my component re-renders as do the grand-children.

```
    render() {
        <div>
            <ThirdPartyComponent props={blah}>
                {this.props.products.map(prod => <MyGrandChildrenComponents product={prod} />
            </ThirdPartyComponent>
        </div>
    }
```

A concrete example can be found on this code sandbox: [codesandbox.io/s/silly-grass-7frlx](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-grass-7frlx)

I'd expect my MyGrandChildrenComponents component to get updated when this.props.products changes... Any hints?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can reproduce this in https://codesandbox.io

Comment: I added a codesandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-grass-7frlx

Comment: Most likely, `ThirdPartyComponent` is a stateful component and is not handling its prop updates correctly. As an experiment, can you pass a `key` prop to the `ThirdPartyComponent` and update the value occasionally and see what happens? In my experience, when the value of `key` gets updated, that component gets re-rendered.

Comment: @ArashMotamedi Gold star for you... Indeed adding a key solved the problem.  I'm not sure I was even aware that changing a key would force a re-render.  Feel free to add this as an actual answer to solve the problem, so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @MattFellows Thanks! Also consider reaching out to the developer of that component if possible to fix/improve the component's behavior. The key prop workaround should not be necessary if the component correctly handles its prop updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if `ThirdPartyComponent` is a stateful component and is not handling its prop updates correctly. One way to force a re-render is to add a `key` prop to your `ThirdPartyComponent` and update its value when a re-render is needed.

```
render() {
        <div>
            <ThirdPartyComponent key={something-that-changes-when-rerender-needed} props={blah}>
                {this.props.products.map(prod => <MyGrandChildrenComponents product={prod} />
            </ThirdPartyComponent>
        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If ThirdPartyComponent is a PureComponent it should re render (and so re render its children) when one of its props changes so you can try:

```
render() {
        <div>
            <ThirdPartyComponent props={blah} products={this.props.products}>
                {this.props.products.map(prod => <MyGrandChildrenComponents product={prod} />
            </ThirdPartyComponent>
        </div>
    }
```

To trigger re renders when `this.props.products` changes.

But any prop should do.

If ThirdPartyComponent has a custom implementation of shouldComponentUpdate, then you will have to find the specific prop which triggers update if it exists.

Comment: Yeah - I had the same thought, tried it and failed...  I'll make a codesandbox using the actula library and see if there's anything specific there rather than my genericised obsfucated ramblings ;)